# asp.net 4.5 cookies not working in Chromium OS

Tags: cookies, chromium, asp.net-4.5

I cant get **Google Chromium OS** to set/read cookies from an ASP.NET 4.5 page.

I am using IIS 8 on windows 8.

Here is the simple web form example:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<script runat="server">

    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

        If Not IsPostBack Then

            Dim cookie As New HttpCookie("TestCookie")
            cookie.Expires = Date.UtcNow.AddDays(1)
            cookie.Value = "Hello from Cookie!"
            Response.Cookies.Add(cookie)

        End If

    End Sub

    Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

        Dim cookie As HttpCookie = Request.Cookies("TestCookie")
        If Not IsNothing(cookie) Then
            Label1.Text = cookie.Value
        Else
            Label1.Text = "Cookie not found!"
        End If

    End Sub

</script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

When I click the button to read the cookie - it always returns Nothing (cookie not found)

I have checked my cookie settings are enabled in Chromium.

When I check the Chromium settings to see what cookies are being stored, it lists only the **ASPNET Session ID** cookie from my website domain, so it is storing the session cookie.

Has anybody else experienced this issue?

I am using IIS 8 on Windows 8.